# in webgl, mod function giving incorrect results in fragment shader if the input came from an int uniform

Tags: webgl, opengl-es-2.0, fragment-shader

I am encountering something weird. If I set an int uniform passed into a fragment shader, and then do some math with it in the shader, I get different results than if I set an int variable inside the shader to the same value.

I have made a test case to demonstrate, go to
https://shaderfrog.com/app/view/4630
It will render a green rectangle with a blue bar.
scroll down to the uniforms and set tileXSize to 28.
The bar should turn red. This means when I did 56 mod 28 the answer came back as 28, where I am expecting to get a 0.
If you uncomment out line 44, setting the int to 28 inside the shader, then the math seems to work correctly, and it shows a white bar.

(blue bar means the input wasn't 28, and thus confirms we have actually set it to 28 when we get the red or white bars).

What am I doing wrong/what have I misunderstood? Have I done something boneheaded, or found some boundary case?

Comment: Just linking to code offsite is off topic for stack overflow. You need to put the code in the quesiton itself. Voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be due to floating point **rounding errors**.
If you add another test. eg.
**This will be true.**

```
if(test <= 28.0) {
  gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);       // black
}
```

But..
**This will be false.**

```
if(test <= 27.9) {
  gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);       // black
}
```

So the number is between 27.9 and 28.0

Answer (score 0):

When `testint` is set via the uniform `tileXSize`, then the maths is being done by the GPU, probably using single precision float accuracy. Possibly `mod` is implemented in some clever way that improves performance but reduces accuracy.

When `testint` is hardcoded in the fragment shader, the shader compiler will realize that the expression can be evaluated once at compile time rather than once for every pixel. The evaluation at compile time will be done on the CPU and gets a slightly different result. It's hard to know why exactly, maybe the maths is done at a higher precision (e.g. double precision float), or maybe it recognizes that both parameters to `mod` are integer and uses integer math instead of floating point for the calculation, or maybe it's just because it's a different math library or different processor.

[This](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/) is an excellent article about the perils and alternatives to testing for equality with floating point numbers. The general rule with floating point is that you'll get extremely accurate answers to most calculations, but you shouldn't generally expect *precise* answers.